# I need to do automation testing on an iOS app that I do not own source code

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, automation, ios-simulator

I would need a serious and robust answer for this please.

Is it possible to automate an iOS app from the store, without owning the source code?

As an alternative, because i have managed to extract the ipa file from the store, can i create a .app file that can be loaded in the XCode simulator?

I got the .app bundle from the Payload folder but a developer said he could not load it to the Xcode simulator.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, what does "automate" mean? What is it you want to do with it? Also... this sounds very suspect.

Comment: Automation testing. Please only robust answers

Comment: No, you wouldn't be able to do this. Automation Testing is something done on the project. Not on the app. You may be able to hack something together that does some really bespoke stuff like tapping areas of the screen etc... But nothing like automation testing. Also, I'm not sure what a "robust answer" is? Trust your developer though :)

Comment: I already mentioned i do NOT own the source code. I need to automate the app via Appium or any other tool. Are there any ideas how to extract or create an .app file from the .ipa extracted from the App Store that i can load to the XCode simulator in order to use Appium inspector? Or any other ideas? Please only useful answers, thanks

Comment: Please stop repeating the request for "Only useful answers" That's what everyone is trying to provide.

Comment: Thanks all for your help

Comment: You really need to realise that the people here (everyone here) are here to try and help you. Constantly requesting "only robust and useful answers" is not necessary. I know you don't have access to the source code. That's why you created the question. You don't have to repeat that in a comment also.

Comment: You can sideload an _ipa_ onto the simulator using Xcode’s Devices window.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how could i do that?

Comment: Oh, no, sorry, you can only do that onto a device. You can sideload an _ipa_ onto a simulator directly from the Finder. No Xcode involvement.

Comment: But an ipa is not designed to run on a simulator. From the store ipa that i extracted, how can i create an .app bundle to load to the Xcode simulator and run it there?

Comment: Okay, you are right, you’d need a _.app_ file to sideload to the simulator, and you cannot make one from your _.ipa_.

Comment: I did get the .app file from the payload folder but the developer said he could not load it to the simulator

Comment: Yes, I can understand that. Apps have entitlements inside them that tell the device/simulator whether to accept them or not. All of this is very strictly regulated by high security foo, and you are trying to get around it. You are trying to do something you're not supposed to do.

Comment: There is also the more fundamental problem that an App Store ipa will contain ARM64 code and the simulator needs x86 code, so there is no way you can run an App Store build on the simulator.

Comment: Yes I know I am not supposed to do that, but there is no way I have access to the source code. Automation with screenshots is a pain in the ass. Another hack that i tried to do is i converted the .app bundle from the Payload folder to .ipa. I installed in to the device with iTools without problem and the app is fully functional. Now, i want to see if UFT object spy can pick up elements because supposedly i have stripped the app from the Store properties. Its no more an Enterprise app